# Знаки препинания в деловом письме

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания поставить в деловом письме в след. случае:
"На основании Вашего поручения.......сообщаю следующее (вот тут какой знак препинания ставить, если далее с нового абзаца идет суть того, что сделано, но не пунктами 1,2,3 а целым тесктом.)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, не стоит начинать поясняющий текст с абзаца, потому что мысль не закончена, что не очень красиво выглядит. Но если он вам так необходим, то ставьте точку, потому что заканчивать абзац, который не открывает списка или тому подобного, двоеточием неграмотно.